# Java Errors when I forked the https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable repository

Tags: eclipse

I am not able to resolve the compiliation errors when I forked the https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable repository. Can someone help me to resolve the issues. Looks like issues related to project build settings.

[image]

Comment: Please add some more information: what java version do you have installed, what IDE are you using? And why the PDFBox label?

Comment: I am able to solve the issues after adding  Lombok plugin for Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is resolved after adding Lombok plugin for Eclipse